# Regularization of singular linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0&B_3&-B_2 \\ -B_3&0&B_1 \\ B_2&-B_1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \omega_1 \\ \omega_2 \\ \omega_3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \Delta_1 \\ \Delta_2 \\ \Delta_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

With $\Delta_1 B_1 + \Delta_2 B_2 + \Delta_3 B_3 = 0$. Because the constraint, the system has clearly solutions in the null space of the $B$ matrix for every possible set of values $\Delta$ that satisfy the constraint.

However, I'm not sure what is the best way to incorporate the constraint into `LinearSolve` so that it will be able to find the whole set of solutions.

I tried replacing one of the $\Delta$ in terms of the others, but no matter which $\Delta$ I choose to replace in terms of the others, I keep getting solutions where $\omega_3$ will be zero. This seems weird since nothing in the problem makes a special distinction between the last coordinate. I've noticed that `RowReduce` would turn the matrix into

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&-B_1/B_3 \\ 0&1&-B_2/B_3 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

In any case, if I replace $\Delta_1$ with the constraint equation, I get a solution

$$\begin{pmatrix} -\Delta_2 /B_3 \\ -B_2 \Delta_2/B_1 B_3 - \Delta_3/B_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Intuitively, the plane orthogonal to $B$ as a vector contains the elements of $\Delta$ and also a set of solutions to the inhomogeneous system of equations, which can be extended with `NullSpace` in order to construct the whole set of solutions. But I wonder why these solutions are constrained to the $\omega_3 = 0$ subspace in the first place

Code that manifests the issue:

```
LinearSolve[{{0,B3, -B2},{-B3,0,B1},{B2, -B1,0}},{-d2*(B2/B1)-d3*(B3/B1),d2,d3}]
```

Also

```
LinearSolve[{{0,B3, -B2},{-B3,0,B1},{B2, -B1,0}},{d1,-d1*(B1/B2)-d3*(B3/B2),d3}]
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the code

Comment: Not sure what is sought but maybe this will help: `Solve[Flatten[{{{0, B3, -B2}, {-B3, 0, B1}, {B2, -B1, 0}}.{x, y, 
       z} - {d1, d2, d3}, B1*d1 + B2*d2 + B3*d3}] == 0, {x, y, z}, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create some example data:

```
d = {d1, d2, d3};
A = {{B1, B2, B3}};
d = d - PseudoInverse[A].A.d // ComplexExpand // Simplify;
B = {{0, B3, -B2}, {-B3, 0, B1}, {B2, -B1, 0}};
A.d // Simplify

(* {0} *)
```

Now, we augment the system matrix `B` and the right hand side `d`:

```
BB = ArrayFlatten[{{B, - Transpose[A]}, {A, 0}}];
dd = Join[d, {0}];
x = LinearSolve[BB, dd][[1 ;; 3]]
(* {(-B3 d2 + B2 d3)/(B1^2 + B2^2 + B3^2), (B3 d1 - B1 d3)/(B1^2 + B2^2 + B3^2), (-B2 d1 + B1 d2)/(B1^2 + B2^2 + B3^2)} *)
```

Let's test the result:

```
B.x - d // Simplify
A.x // Simplify

(* {0,0,0} *)
(* {0} *)
```

With the augmentation, we enforced that $B_1 \, \omega_1 + B_2 \, \omega_2 + B_3 \, \omega_3 = 0$ and we added the orthogonal complement of the image of `B` to the image of `BB`.

Comment: how is `s` defined?

Comment: @lurscher Sorry, bad typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears ill posed. Call the matrix mat, and define

```
mat = {{0, b3, -b2}, {-b3, 0, b1}, {b2, -b1, 0}};
b = {b1, b2, b3};
d = {d1, d2, d3};
```

You have two conditions: one is that `b.d==0`. The other is that `d==mat.w`, where `w` is the unknown. Substituting `d` into the first equation shows that `b.mat.w==0`. But this is true for all `w`, since `b.mat` is identically zero!

```
b.mat

{0, 0, 0}
```